# coxphw undefined columns selected

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I'm fitting a Cox proportional hazards model and my martginal plot of continuous variable age is not linear. Therefore I would like to use the fp() command to adjust for that. I know I should use coxphw now but R keeps returning the same error:
*Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(formula)) :
undefined columns selected*
The function coxph works just fine. What do I do wrong?

Example with just one explanatory variable Man (binary for gender)

Code:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(survMisc)
library(dplyr)
library(mfp)
library(coxphw)

setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
data = read.csv2("Survival Analysis.csv", header = T)
time = data$Weken.in.dienst
event = data$Status
# model is created without error
model = coxph(Surv(time,event) ~ Man, data = data)
summary(model)
# modelw can't be created
modelw = coxphw(Surv(time,event) ~ Man, data = data)
summary(modelw)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. You must not rename columns to time or event column names. Coxphw does not work properly when you do. I have an event column 'Status' and time column 'Weken.in.dienst'. The correct formula becomes:

```
coxphw(data = data, Surv(Weken.in.dienst, Status) ~ Man)
```